# Makefile echo random

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I define a function to get 10 random nums whose value is [0..9].

```
define write_file
for i in $$( seq 1 10 );\
do\
    RANDOM := $(shell bash -c 'echo $$RANDOM')%10;\
    echo -n $$RANDOM >> test.txt;\
done
endef
```

But when I call it ,the output is:

```
for i in $( seq 1 10 ); do RANDOM := 25401%10; echo $RANDOM; done
/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found

/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found

/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found

/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found

/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found

/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found

/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found

/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found

/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found

/bin/sh: 1: RANDOM: not found
```

I also tried using `echo $RANDOM` rather than `echo $$RANDOM` but it still did not work.

## EDIT

I also tried echo RANDOM in bash shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $( seq 1 10 )
do
    echo ${RANDOM}
done
```

But noting appeared in terminal.

### Correct bash script

From comment,`#!/bin/sh` should be changed to `#!/bin/bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( seq 1 10 )
do
    echo ${RANDOM}
done
```

Comment: Change to `#!/bin/bash`, since `$RANDOM` is a `bash` extension.

Comment: Your makefile is trying to assign a `make` variable in a shell `for` loop. How could that possibly work?

Comment: So how can I get 10 random number?

Comment: When I changed to `bash`,nothing changed.

Comment: The script works for me.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Because even if your first script worked, it just overwrites the variable each time. You don't get 10 random numbers, you just get the last random number of the loop.

Comment: I will explain my quesion clearly.

Comment: Maybe `RANDOM := $(shell /path/to/the/script)`

Comment: @Barmar It's strange the scond bash script works for you.And I want to write 10 random number whose values is [0..9] into a file.

Comment: @Barmar The scond one now works for me.Maybe I forget to save the change.Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
seq 10 | awk 'BEGIN{srand()} {print(int(rand()*10))}' > test.txt
```

or

```
awk -v n=10 'BEGIN{srand(); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print(int(rand()*10))}' > test.txt
```

to get the numbers adjacent, you can do this

```
awk -v n=10 'BEGIN{srand(); 
                   for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                   printf "%d",(int(rand()*10)); 
                   print ""}'
```

redirect to file as above.

Comment: This doesn't show how to get them into `make` variables.

Comment: He added that after I made my comment.

Comment: I want to write 10 random nums whose value is [0..9] into a file.

Comment: It works.But I want 1234567890 format rather than 1<newline>2<newline>3...

Comment: `seq 10 | awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{ORS=""}{print(int(rand()*10))}' >> tmp/test.txt` works for me.  `ORS=""`

Comment: you may want to add a new line at the end.

Comment: No new line is not needed.